# New Continental Hardshells

Tags: tire

Having difficulty bedding my new Gatorskin tyres onto the clincher wheels of my audax bike. Campag Scirrocco wheels. There is a constant 'dip' in the tyre at the same point despite numerous reinflations.

Comment: Is the dip always in the same place relative to the tire or the wheel or neither?

Comment: It's the same place on the tyre

Comment: A picture would help. Sometimes you get a malformed tire.

Comment: If it's same spot on the tire, even after the tire is dismounted and remounted differently relative to the rim (in particular, the valve hole) then it's almost certainly a problem with the tire.  In some cases the tire will "soften" with use and the problem will subside, but that's less likely with a puncture-resistant style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continental tires have a tendency to do this, especially when new. It's very common. Put some soapy water on the bead and temporarily overinflate. That will usually get them to seat.

Answer (score 1):

Clamp the inflated tire (regular pressure) in a well secured workshop vice.  You want to clamp the tire itself at the point where it dips. Then pull on the top of the wheel to force the bead into place. Make sure you only clamp the tire and not the rim and don't forget to flip the wheel and repeat for the bead on the other side.

An LBS showed me this trick when I had a stubborn tire.  At first I thought it was madness, but it really works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all and especially Nathan. I tried the following and it has improved things no end: deflated tyre, ran in talc in the tyre/rim gap, overinflated and rode for 1 hour on local B roads with usual mediocre surfaces.

Comment: If his answer solved your problem, you should click the little check mark to accept it.